# Regex in sublimetext to find specific html element

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext

I want to use regex in sublimetext to find instances of `&nbsp;` in `<td class="danish">&nbsp;</td>`

Can anyone please help me with this?

I've used the following elsewhere before: (?<=danish/).+(?=.swf), but the tag brackets are giving me problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Sublime Text unofficial documentation for Regular Expressions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) it indicates that

> Sublime Text uses the [**Boost syntax**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) for regular expressions.

So you can use positive lookahead and lookbehinds like in the following Regex, if you're sure your `<td>` node does not have any data other than you provided.

```
(?<=\<td class="danish">).*?(&nbsp;)+.*?(?=<\/td>)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for responding. It says "invalid lookbehind assertion"

Comment: My fault, sorry. Just correcting the pattern. The `\s+` became a space now.